# Building Two Animated Lists Inside A Stack With Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two Animated Lists each one of them has certain functionality. The first one build A CheckBoxTile and the second one build ListTile. When i wrapped both of them inside a stack I found that only the list at the end is working in terms functionality. So both of them appears on the screen but only the last one updates the UI with SetState(). As if Flutter does not recognize the functionality of the first one. Here is my stack

```
Stack(children: [
                  AnimatedList(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      key: _listKeyCheckBox,
                      initialItemCount: workoutsMap
                          .workoutsMap[value]['$muscleName'].length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              setState(() {
                                val = true;
                              });
                            },
                            child: CheckboxListTile(
                              value: val,
                              onChanged: (changedValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  val = changedValue;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                  AnimatedList(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    key: _listKey,
                    initialItemCount: workoutObjects.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _checkWidgets(index);
                          setState(() {});

                   
                        },
                        child: SlideTransition(
                          child: workoutObjects[index],
                          position: animation.drive(_offset),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                ]),
```

As you see the first Animated List for the CheckBoxListTile does not update the val so the UI does not update too.